Parking sensors and towbar, how to diagnose
I've got a 2009 Ford Galaxy that has front and rear parking sensors.  We went away last weekend in our caravan and so had to attach our detachable towbar.
There's a probem with the towbar now meaning it won't detach, which is actually ok because we need to use it quite a lot over the summer anyway.  But, the rear parking sensor is bleeping almost constantly now.
I can't detach the towbar to see if that's what's actually causing it, and what's muddying the waters is that i noticed that one of the sensors had been pushed into the bumper and was partially obscured by the bumper due to pointing sideways a bit.  "Ah that must be it!" i thought and put it back into position, but it's still beeping.
So the two possibilities seem to be

it is the towbar, which seems weird because it's really not in the line of sight of any of the sensors
the sensor that was bashed into the bumper was damaged in the process, and is malfunctioning.

How can I find out which is the case, any ideas?  If it's possible to just disconnect that one sensor then I could see if it goes back to working ok without that sensor, and order a new one.
